# How to handle multiple requests to a file in node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

I'm trying to serve multiple audio files in the node.js server, but the server sometimes fails when multiple clients try to access. How can I remedy this?

```
express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();

app.get('/', function (request, response) {
    let fpath = base_dir + filenames[getIndex(filenames.length)];
    let filestream = fs.createReadStream(fpath);
    var d = new Date();

    filestream.on('open', function() {
        let stats = fs.statSync(fpath);
        let fileSizeInBytes = stats["size"];
        response.writeHead(200, {
            "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
            'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
            'Content-Length': fileSizeInBytes});
        filestream.pipe(response);
    });
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Audio file provider listening on port 3000');
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using [`fs.statSync()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_statsync_path) which will block the thread also listening for incoming connections. Instead you should switch to the asynchronous version [`fs.stat()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback).

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let fpath = base_dir + filenames[getIndex(filenames.length)]
    let d = new Date()

    fs.stat(fpath, (err, stats) => {
        // Handle Error when trying to get file stats
        // Respond with 500 Internal Server Error
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
          return res.sendStatus(500)
        }

        let {size} = stats
        res.status(200)
        res.setHeader('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes')
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'audio/mpeg')
        res.setHeader('Content-Length', size)

        fs.createReadStream(fpath).pipe(res)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're already using express, no need to reinvent the wheel http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile

```
app.get('/', function (request, response) {
    let fpath = base_dir + filenames[getIndex(filenames.length)];

    response.sendFile(fpath, function(err) {
        //Handle err if any
    });
})
```